# Counting multiple items with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to implement a shopping cart with Redux. My React code fetches product information from database and renders that for user to see. Here is a sample of my `App.js`:

```
function GetProductsHtml() {
    initProducts()
    const AddItem = (ProductID) => {
      store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
      store.dispatch(AddItemToCart())
    }
    return products.map(products =>
      <div key={products.ProductID}>
        <h2>{products.ProductName}</h2>
        <h2>{products.ProductDescription}</h2>
        <h2>{products.ProductQuantity} units available</h2>
        
        <button onClick={AddItem(products.ProductID)}>Add to cart</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

With this code each product gets "add to cart" button of it's own, but the problem is that they all increment one single counter, so I have tried to pass `ProductID` as a parameter to my Redux reducer. Here is my `cart.js`:

```
export const AddItemToCart = (productID) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADDITEMTOCART',
        productID
    }
}
export const DeleteItemFromCart = (productID) => {
    return {
        type: 'DELETEITEMFROMCART',
        productID
    }
}
export const Counter = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADDITEMTOCART':
            state.push({
                key:   action.productID,
                value: value + 1
            });
            return state;
        case 'DELETEITEMFROMCART':
            state.push({
                key:   action.productID,
                value: value - 1
            });
            return state;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to use dictionary with key-value pairs (`ProductID` being the key and quantity being the value). But Babel fails to compile and says "value is not defined". Any advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any advise guys? :)

Comment: Still looking for solution... I will place some bounty award as soon as I can.

Comment: There's a bunch of things that can be improved here.  Don't interact with the store instance directly with `store.dispatch`.  Use the `useDispatch` hook instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see, I have tried to use dictionary with key-value pairs (ProductID being the key and quantity being the value).

It is always smart to store the minimum amount of necessary data, so you have the right idea here.  The problem is that it's not being implemented properly.  Instead of an array of key-value objects, let's make the state be a single object that maps from the ids to the quantities.  It should look like this:

```
{
  123: 1, // cart contains 1 of product id #123
  999: 2, // cart contains 2 of product id #999
}
```

---

When you are writing a reducer as function is important that you must **never mutate the state**.  You need to always return a copied version.  So you cannot call `.push()` (you would use `.concat()` instead for adding array items).

```
export const Counter = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADDITEMTOCART':
          return {
            ...state, // copy all other quanities
            // update this property by adding 1 to the current quanity
            // or just add with quantity 1 if it didn't already exist
            [action.productID]: ( state[action.productID] || 0 ) + 1
          }
      case 'DELETEITEMFROMCART':
          return {
            ...state,
            [action.productID]: ( state[action.productID] || 1 ) - 1
          }
      default:
          return state;
  }
}
```

Note that we might have cart entries with `0` quantity, so you probably want to filter those out before rendering.

---

There is an easier way to write reducers which is by using [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice).  With the toolkit, your reducer can make mutations on a draft version of the state.  You don't need to return a new state.  You just change the properties that you want to change.

If you know for sure that the `id` in `action.payload` already exists in the cart then you can change the quantity just by writing `state[action.payload]++;` or `state[action.payload]--;`.  But if the key isn't in the object already then you get `NaN` by doing this.  So we have to check.

It also makes the action-creator functions automatically!  Note that they use the property `payload` instead of `productID`.

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState = {},
  reducers: {
    // increase the cart quantity by 1
    addItemToCart(state, action) {
      // the current cart quantity - is 0 if not in cart
      const currentAmount = state[action.payload] ?? 0;
      state[action.payload] = currentAmount + 1;
    },
    // decrease the cart quantity by 1
    decrementQuantity(state, action) {
      // subtract 1 from quantity if there are multiple in the cart
      if (state[action.payload] > 1) {
        state[action.payload]--;
      }
      // delete from cart if the quantity was 1 (or not found)
      else {
        delete state[action.payload];
      }
    },
    // remove this product from the cart entirely
    deleteItemFromCart(state, action) {
      delete state[action.payload];
    }
  }
});

// export action creators
export const { addItemToCart, decrementQuantity, deleteItemFromCart } = cartSlice.actions;

// export reducer
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

---

Let's assume that your store has reducers for `cart` and `products`.  So the cart data would be at `state.cart`.

Here's how your components might look:

```
// component that displays a single product
function RenderProduct({ product }) {
  // access the dispatch function from a hook
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // can get cart information via a selector
  // get the number of this item already in the cart
  const numberInCart = useSelector((state) => state.cart[product.ProductID]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{product.ProductName}</h2>
      <h2>{product.ProductDescription}</h2>
      <h2>{product.ProductQuantity} units available</h2>
      {product.ProductQuantity > 1 ? (
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(addItemToCart(product.ProductID))}>
          Add to cart
        </button>
      ) : (
        "Sold Out"
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function ProductsList() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // some selector that gets the products array
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);

  useEffect(() => {
    // some action that loads products into the state
    dispatch(loadProductData());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      {(products || []).map((product) => (
        <RenderProduct key={product.ProductID} product={product} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for taking the time to answer. The difficulty here comes from the fact that I don't know in advance how many products there are in database, so I cannot hardcode the dictionary keys, but you solved that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The value keyword in expression value-1 and value+1 is the issue. value keyword is not defined.
so to increment/decrement the quantity of a particular product, you need to find the current quantity. Here in case of increment, first, you need to find the item and update the quantity of the item if the item is not present in the array simply add the item and when you decrement the quantity you find the item if the quantity is already less then 1 remove the item otherwise decrease the quantity.

```
export const Counter = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADDITEMTOCART':
            let itemIndex = state.findIndex(x => x.productID == action.productID);
           if(itemIndex != -1){
             state.push({
               key:   action.productID,
               value: value + 1
             });
            } else {
              state[itemIndex].value +=1; 
             }
            return [...state];
        case 'DELETEITEMFROMCART':
            let itemIndex = state.findIndex(x => x.productID == action.productID);
            state[itemIndex].value -=1;
            if(state[itemIndex].value == 0){
              state.splice(itemIndex, 1);
            }
            return [...state];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are declaring itemIndex twice, is that a purpose? Also, can you give an example of how to access a specific product quantity (by ProductID) from App.js?

Comment: no, the itemIndex is declared in a different case block, so this will not cause any issue. To access the specific product quantity in App.js. just connect your component (App.js) with redux. and then use this  `const item = state.find(x => x.productID == productID)` in item variable you will get quantity. the state in here is the key name of the redux where you save the cart items.

Comment: Unfortunately this fails to compile. Babel says "identifier itemIndex has already been declared"

Comment: ok, you can use different variable name for these block

Comment: I moved the itemIndex declaration between switch and export statements, but the original error is still showing up. Can you run that at your own compiler?

Comment: This code will mutate the state with `state.splice` and `state.push`.  State mutation is not allowed.